# How to pass variable values from java to javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I am a beginner in coding. I have met a scenario to pass the variable values from a java class to javascript and that need to be updated as values of a high chart in javascript.

[image: [java code: I need to pass this values of float variables from this java class to JS]

These values need to be updated in the below chart in JS.

[image: java scripts]

Kindly help me to code this scenario.

Comment: This might help, ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28164843/how-to-pass-variables-from-java-class-to-java-script

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To pass variables from java class to Java Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28164843/how-to-pass-variables-from-java-class-to-java-script)

Comment: Please include the required code as text in the question, not in screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
  url: "YourSeveletPathName",
  type: 'GET',
  success: function(response) {
    //console.log(response);
    //map your data here -  to  series parameter in your highchart method.
  },
  error: function(error) {
    errorFunction(error, parameter);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller class you can put the data in an array and send to your jsp :

```
request.setAttribute("mydata", mydataarray);
```

In your Electricity.jsp you can get parameters as :

```
var jsvarlist=<%=request.getAttribute("mydata") %>;
```

> Note: javascript doesn't want explicit data types

---

In your JS file you can pass the list at your function , as it is an array you can get data in this way :

```
jsvarlist[0] //first value etc..
```

if you need to import such java class in your jsp , you should use :

```
 <%@ page import ="yourpackage.yourclass" %>
```

In the end import the JS file to your jsp and call your function who accept the list now :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="yourfile.js"></script>
... call your function
```

Comment: you also need to `set` `something` in request also.

Comment: Hi Frank,

The code for chart has written in java scripts (Electricity.js) which internally called by 'Electricity.jsp'.
I am calling the 'container1' from the 'Electricity.jsp' and displays the chart in JSP.

Comment: <div class="content-wrapper less-margin"> <div class="content-area">
            <div id="container1" style="width:100%; height: 500px; float:left;display:inline-block;margin-bottom: 50px"></div></div> </div>
  <script src="javascripts/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/bootstrap-3.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/Electricity.js"></script>

Comment: Pls provide me the information to insert the values in to the chart.
-Bibin

Comment: Edited , hope may can help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use ajax for doing that.

```
 var series = this.series[0];
 $.get("YourServletName",function(data){
                        series.addPoint([data.x, data.y], true, true);
                    });
                 }, 1000);
```

In the above code: `the var series = this.series[0];` is your array,
the `$get` method is the method which retrieves the data from your servlet,
the `series.addPoint([data.x, data.y], true, true);` is adding each point to the series.
And before all these in your servlet you must have something like this:

```
JsonObjectBuilder j = Json.createObjectBuilder();
        //Create code for your getting what you want and set this result to "y".

        j.add("x", System.currentTimeMillis());
        j.add("y", YourResult);
        out.println(j.build());
```

Comment: Hi Fortis,

Thank you for your valuable information.

Comment: If my question helped you please accepted and give an up vote!

Comment: I am done & i am getting this message.

'Thanks for the feedback. Votes cast by those less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicity displayed post score'

Comment: Thank you me dear @Bibin Vs. You can accepted also by pressing the grey tick. :)